# pandas .groupby() returning a string instead of an integer

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am working with a dataset, and I need to group by data by age categories. I created my categories and used the following code which returns the correct number of unique people in each group: For reference unique_players looks like this:
[image]

```
age_demographics = unique_players[['Age','Age Categories']].groupby(['Age Categories']).count()
```

I use age as a proxy for my count of people in each category. So I renamed the column, and checked for type:

```
age_demographics = age_demographics.rename(columns = {"Age": "Count"})
```

After doing this, the data looks like this:[image]

This correctly changes the name of the column and when I checked type it showed up as string. So I tried to convert to numeric:

```
age_demographics['Count'] = pd.to_numeric(age_demographics['Count'], errors = 'coerce')
```

Even after doing this, the type is returned as string. I can do `.describe()` which returns all descriptive stats of my counts no issue.

This is the output from age_demographics.describe() looks like:
[image]

Any suggestion on how to correct this?

Comment: Hmm.. that's peculiar. Can you please provide a few cells of the original `df`? It might be easier for others to see where the disconnect is.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I just added snips of all my output for each step. Thank you for reviewing my question

Comment: what does `age_demographics.dtypes` bring up? Also, if the pandas built-in function does not work, maybe we can do `age_demographics['Count'] = age_demographics['Count'].apply(lambda col: int(col))`

Comment: `DataFrame.astype(int)` would do the job, r.ather than `.apply`